# Google Analytics only show real-time data and not historic data

Tags: google-analytics

I have a webform site where I added the Google Analytics script, but the Google Analytics Home just shows real-time data and not historic data like Page Views, Session by Device, Session by country, etc.

[image: Google Analytics Home]
The script looks like this (it was inserted after ):

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1');
</script>
```

Comment: There is a add on for Chrome to check if Analytic's code is installed properly. But other than that, you need to check this with Google Analytic's support

Comment: That's what I thought but where is the Google Analytic's support?

Comment: The Google Analytics Debugger and the Tag Assistant (by Google) extension doesn't show anything wrong.

Comment: I think only premium accounts can access support... check every GA option in the menu (adquisition, audience, conversions, etc). Also the date period you are listing, and if there is any filter, remove it. If the code installation is fine, and the code is fine, and it was runnig for a few days, it should work... I have several web sites (more than 30) and I never have a problem like this. You could also check in another brower

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It takes a while to show historic data, 1 or 2 days at least.

Comment: I just made the switch from a UA Tag to a GA tag. I see real-time data but no historic data. Are you sure this still holds true?